# Create Controls by click Button in runtime in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add label in runtime when you click the button, 
this is my code but when you click the button it just add new label in new position and the label you made before by click that button is not showing
and i want to show all of them one by one after click button
how can i fix it?

```
Label lbl;
int number;
int locationX = 2;
int locationY = 4;

public void CreateRuntimeControl(PictureBox pic)
{
    lbl; = new Label();
    number++;
    locationX++;
    locationY++;
    lbl.Name = "lbl" + number.ToString();
    lbl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 50);
    lbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10 + locationX, 10 + locationY);
    lbl.Text = number.ToString();
    lbl.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    pic.Controls.Add(lbl);
}
```

Best Regards

Comment: You are setting your x and y coordinates 1 pixel different for each label therefore they are on top of each other. Try LocationY += 50;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**************************************************************************************************************i found my answer and i want to put it here to if anyone else has my problem find this page and fix the problem

---

```
        int number;
    int locationX;
    int locationY;

    public void CreateRuntimeControl(PictureBox pic)
    {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        number++;
        locationX++;
        locationY = locationY + 100;
        lbl.Name = "lbl" + number.ToString();
        lbl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 50);
        lbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10 + locationX, 10 + locationY);
        lbl.Text = number.ToString();
        lbl.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        pic.Controls.Add(lbl);
    }
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should move the  lbl = new Label(); statement to the body of the CreateRuntimeControl() function, otherwise you are re-using the same label and just moving it instead of creating new one

Comment: it made some label but now after move the code its not showing the new label text (it just show the first text) and there isn't any space between labels,  what should i do?

Comment: You are adding multiple lables to PictureBox control? PictureBox is for displaying pictures, it's not to display many text labels. Maybe you should create a separate panel and add your labels to it

Comment: but i want to add multi labels on picturebox,  what should i do?

Comment: and i test it on panel but the same problem with adding labels

Comment: You should add the labels not to the picturebox, but to the same control where PictureBox is added, *before* picture box is added (otherwise PictureBox will hide your labels). Also you should increase your locationX and locationY by more than 1, otherwise it would be difficult to see new labels, they will overlap

Comment: thanks man, i found my answer, and the labels size will be going very more small than now

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int number;
int locationX = 2;
int locationY = 4;

public void CreateRuntimeControl(PictureBox pic)
{
    Label lbl = new Label();
    number++;
    locationX++;
    locationY++;
    lbl.Name = "lbl" + number.ToString();
    lbl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 50);
    lbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10 + locationX, 10 + locationY);
    lbl.Text = number.ToString();
    lbl.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    pic.Controls.Add(lbl);
}
```

Comment: it made some label but now after move the code its not showing the new label text (it just show the first text) and there isn't any space between labels, what should i do?

Comment: did you put `lbl` into `CreateRuntimeControl?` my mean's property of `lbl `not its constructor...